# To Group By Hire Date in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Assume the following table

**Employee**

```
EmployeeID           INT
FirstName            VARCHAR(50)
LastName             VARCHAR(50)
SupervisorEmployeeID INT
Salary               MONEY
HireDate             DATETIME
```

1. How to show the number of employees hired per year for the last 5 years also include the average salary for employees hired in those years.
2. How to show the number of employees hired per year for the last 5 years also include the average salary for employees hired in those years.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(EmployeeID )
FROM Employee
WHERE MONTHS_BETWEEN(getdate(), HireDate) <= 60;

Comment: Are Q1 and Q2 supposed to be the same?

Comment: Yes for correction :)

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the DatePart function in SQL. It will break up and group dates based on the interval supplied (ie. day, month, year, etc.)

Sample:

```
SELECT
    DatePart(year,HireDate)
    ,Count(emplid)
    ,AVG(salary)
FROM Employee
WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR, HireDate, GetDate) <= 4
GROUP BY DatePart(year,HireDate) 
ORDER BY DatePart(year,HireDate) asc
```

Comment: is DatePart() is in-built function in MSSQL? @nicholas

Comment: Don't forget year 0, 0 (current year), 1 (last year), etc. This would show 5 years total (including current year).